# Rails 3.2 Upgrade - Vendor/Plugins Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, heroku

Good afternoon,

I just upgraded my Rails app from 3.1.3 to 3.2.1.  Everything is working on my local development machine (in development or production modes).  There is no trace left of my vendor/plugins directory (or even the vendor directory at all).

However, after committing to git and pushing to Heroku, I'm getting warnings about deprecation of my rails 2.3 style vendor/plugins.  Crazy seeing as I have no vendor directory at all!

Do I need to totally wipe my Heroku files?  (If so, how would I do this?)  Any other suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this and it looks like warnings about some of the stuff that Heroku injects into your code for things such as asset serving etc.

I'm assuming that as more and more start to use Rails 3.2 that Heroku will fix this.  I wouldn't worry about it - the deprecation won't kick in until Rails 4.0 and that's some way off.

Comment: Good to hear - thanks for letting me know it's not on my end!